# Where is user/group id info stored on Android

Tags: android

I know one way to find the applications uid/group info in /data/system/packages.list

But if i want to know other applications uid/group info, such as mediaserver. where can i get from android device? looks like, I can find such info from init.rc. But is there other place can get such full information?

thanks